# Chrome text gets blurry on opacity transition

Tags: css, hover, transform, css-transitions, opacity

Okay, the good ol' issue with blurred text on chrome.

I'm creating a CSS dropdown menu that transitions from `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0` to `visibility: visible` and `opacity: 1` and the text gets slightly blurred.

This issue is not present on Firefox. There the text is crisp.

You can see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swum8rm7/1/

By removing the transition on *line 21* you see that the text becomes sharp. I tried all kinds of `translateZ` and `backface` shenanigans and can't get it to work properly.

Comment: its all sharp for me, i am using chromium.

Comment: I may be kind of perfectionist but look here: http://i.imgur.com/wLRgEF9.png
I upped the `font-size` to `20px`.
The text on the right is slightly blurred (not the "Hover Me" one, the lines bellow it).

Comment: its not that the font is blurry ( I counted Pixels ), but yeah it seams to have lower contrast.

Comment: Hey, i am having the same issue. Have you solved this?

Comment: Still no, searched everywhere and still..

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/ Anyone who suffers from blurry text should read this old article by Paul Lewis. In short it's mainly all about Subpixel antialiasing quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` makes the text a lot better (although it is still somewhat blurry)